# Attaching substring to multiple lists of strings

Tags: python

I have multiple lists of strings and I need to attach substring to each. This is how I went about doing it.

```
def attachSub(l, substr):
    return [str+substr for str in l]
substr = 'substring'
myList = attachSub(myList, substr)
myList2 = attachSub(myList, substr)
myList3 = attachSub(myList, substr)
```

Now if I have dozens of lists how can I do this operation more compactly than manually calling `attachSub()` on each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

You can create a list of lists called `listOfLists` and then create a `for` loop over it, thus applying your function to each of the lists within `listOfLists`. See the example provided below.

### Example

---

#### Setting up the example

First we define a function for random string generation, of a fixed length ([as this PYnative site shows](https://pynative.com/python-generate-random-string/)).

```
import random
import string

def randomString(stringLength=6):
    """Generate a random string of fixed length """
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))
```

Next, still for the example, we define a function that creates a list of random strings.

```
def listRandStrings(stringLengthsVec):
    """Generate a list of random strings"""
    randListStrings = []
    for x in stringLengthsVec:
        randListStrings.append(randomString(x))
    return randListStrings
```

Finally, we have an example of a list of lists:

```
listOfLists =  [listRandStrings([3,5,2,3]),listRandStrings([5,6]),listRandStrings([2,3,4])]
```

**Note** that in your case, if there is a function that returns these lists of yours, you can make `listOfLists=[]` and then iteratively append your lists with `listOfLists.append(myNewList())`.

---

#### And now for the solution

```
for j in range(len(listOfLists)):
    listOfLists[j]=attachSub(listOfLists[j],'Substring')
```

In the `for` loop, `j` goes from 0 to (length of `listOfLists`) - 1. For each list inside `listOfLists`, your function `attachSub()` is performed.